# Why can't I use `this` in $.each function as string arg for jQuery function

Tags: jquery, each

I'm struggling with some jQuery code I'm working on, and I've narrowed down the problem to this simple example that doesn't behave as I would expect it too:

**jsFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/HypYT/

---

**HTML**

```
<div id="a">a: <span>A</span></div>
<div id="b">b: <span>B</span></div>​
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery.each( ["#a", "#b"], function(){
    alert(this);    // alerts "#a" and "#b"
    $(this).hide(); //not working
    $('#b').hide(); //working
});​
```

---

Anyone have any insight what's going on here?

Comment: Thanks. In the console, I saw the "object" type, but I just assumed it was one of those "everythings an object" things with js lol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a function is called on a string (or other primitive), `this` becomes a boxed object.
`typeof this` will therefore return `"object"`, not `"string"`.
This breaks jQuery.  (no pun intended)

You can fix this by forcing it back to a string primitive:

```
$(String(this)).hide()
```

You can fix this for arbitrary primitives by writing

```
var self = this.constructor(this);
```

However, using the second argument passed to `.each()` will be faster, because it will avoid boxing in the first place.

Comment: use argument as Fabricio mentioned above. It's way faster.

Comment: Actually I'd just use a `for` loop when performance is concerned but yeah, it works. `=]`

Answer (score 6):

Adding to [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12497864/297641) answer, You can use the arg passed to `.each`. See below,

```
jQuery.each( ["#a", "#b"], function(idx, el){
    alert(this);    // alerts "#a" and "#b"
    $(el).hide(); 
    //$('#b').hide(); 
});​
```

or You can do

```
var elToHide = $(["#a", "#b"].join()).hide();
$(elToHide.join()).hide()
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/HypYT/2/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do:

```
$('#a, #b').hide();
```

Comment: thanks xdazz, but that's not really what I was going for.  I'll be using an array of several selectors and performing several options with each.

Comment: @ZachL You can do this `$(["#a", "#b"].join()).hide()`

Answer (score 1):

the each function works in this way (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
$.each([52, 97], function(index, value) { 
  alert(index + ': ' + value); 
});
```

so in your case

```
jQuery.each( ["#a", "#b"], function(index, value){
    alert(value);    // alerts "#a" and "#b"
    $(value).hide(); //not working
});
```

​
The explanation is (taken from the link) that 
"The value can also be accessed through the this keyword, but Javascript will always wrap the this value as an Object even if it is a simple string or number value."